# NUnit addins not loading

Tags: nunit, nunit-addins

I am trying to load some addins to the NUnit Gui Runner, however it doesn't identify any addin at all even that they are all inside the addins directory.
I even compiled their examples and tried to load them but still nothing.
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

The nUnit version being linked to by the addin doesn't match the one in the current nUnit download.

I looked into recompiling the source for the addin, but ran into other issues.

I've just broken out my tests into individual tests and call the method I was trying to use for the row tests.

--Edit--
I found the answer for my issue.  http://nunit.org/?p=testCase&r=2.5 I was trying to use an addin that is no longer supported (and had been built in for some time)

--Edit 2--
We're not the only ones to have trouble http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2009/05/10/NUnit25Support.aspx

Comment: I have downloaded NUnit msi, compiled the samples and same effect.